# NotImplementedException in Hippomock's MockRepository::BasicRegisterExpect

Tags: c++, exception, mocking, expectations, hippomocks

While trying to register an expectation using Hippomock's `MockRepository::ExpectCall` I encounter the `NotImplementedException` exception at `MockRepository::BasicRegisterExpect`'s following line which I admittedly do not understand:

```
if ((unsigned int)baseOffset * sizeof(void*) + sizeof(void*)-1 > sizeof(Z)) RAISEEXCEPTION(NotImplementedException(this));
```

Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the exception using a stripped down example.

Hence my "simple" questions:

- In which cases is this very exception raised when expecting a call?
- What does this code line exactly test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case the exception was due to my trying to mock a non-virtual class function. Simple answer, but so easy to overlook...

Answer (score 0):

On what version was this and on which platform (compiler, version, settings) ? It should let you know with a nice message instead; if it gets to that line it thinks it's a virtual function and it's wrong.

Comment: As I said in my own answer it was due to my trying to mock a non-virtual class function. I'm using Visual C++ 2010 and it was using Hippomocks 3.1 if I remember well. If I can reproduce the error with the current version I'll let you know. Thanks all the same for the answer!